# Hadoop file splits

Tags: hadoop, bigdata

I want to put a large file into Hadoop file system. It will be splitted in blocks of 64 mb ( or 128mb) and it's probable that these blocks , despite belonging to a specific file, are distributed along different nodes in the cluster.

I know that hadoop complies with Shared-nothing paradigm, so memory is not shared. If a certain node wants to elaborate the initial file, it will copy every 64mb (or 128mb ) block from the nodes where the various blocks were sent to its local memory ?

ps: when a file is splitted in 64 mb(or 128mb) blocks , it is simply truncated at multiples of 64 mb(or 128mb) or some other procedure is applied ?

Comment: Sorry, not understanding the question. Divide your file by the HDFS block size (and round up), then that's how many blocks

Comment: it is simply truncated. in some case rows are cut to different Block.